# Can a hacker use a MAC address and steal data or my identity?

Tags: mac

I was staying at a hotel, and could not get online in the room via the hotel's wireless system. I called the "technology department" who asked me for my MAC address, which he told me how to look up.

After giving him the info, he played around for a few minutes, but was unable to solve the problem. The line got cut off, and when I called back, another person in the tech dept asked me what browser I was using. I use Chrome, but he suggested I try Internet Explorer. That solved the problem, without my having to give away any "private" information.

> Can the first person, who knows my MAC address, hack into my computer with it?

Comment: About the only use I can think that a hacker might make of your MAC is to go round to your home or office and connect to the WiFi network there, but only if it uses MAC validation. If a hacker found out where to go to do this, it would give access to all the vulnerabilities normally allowed on a trusted network, including network shares and open TCP/IP ports which are otherwise protected by the router's firewall.

Answer (score 7):

No, he can't. MAC addresses are broadcast on a network by default, it's how switches figure out where traffic should go. Anyone that cared could easily observe many of the MAC addresses of the devices on their network.